# AsyncStorage.setItem Callback Always Null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use AsyncStorage to set a value and it always seems to be setting null. I've used async/await in order to do this but I've also tried to whittle down the troubleshooting to just setting a value and checking the callback and I'm still getting null. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('something', 'VALUE') 
  .then((val) => { 
    this.setState({storageValue: val ? val : 'EMPTY'});
  })
```

This always gives me "EMPTY" in my state.

Comment: The callback for `setItem` will only give you an error, if an error occurred. It does not give you the value that you set. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#setitem

Comment: According to the documentation, `setItem()` can be called with a third parameter, an optional error callback. Your `val` is most likely `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try out my other code and re-ask this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find it in the documentation but according to the sample code code setItem does not seem to return anything (the result is ignored in sample code) so maybe the promise does not resolve to anything either.

You could try setting it and then getting it:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('something', 'VALUE')
.then(x => AsyncStorage.getItem('something')
.then((val) => { 
  this.setState({storageValue: val ? val : 'EMPTY'});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't just use whatever you're passing into the setItem? You can use that same variable:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('something', val) 
  .then(() => this.setState({storageValue: val ? val : 'EMPTY'}))
```

Comment: The scenario is kind of different from how I was testing this. I was setting it, then trying to access it later on using jest. As I said, I was trying to whittle it down to the most basic scenario I could figure out in order to pin down what was wrong.

Comment: I was using it for debugging and initial testing. If it returns a value on-success then checking that value would have been a good indicator of success

Comment: The promise should only resolve if it is successful, otherwise it should go to the catch statement.